# Theming a node in Drupal 7 (a node generated with a specific content type)

Tags: forms, drupal-7, field, theming

I continue to develop my first module and I've a last problem. In fact, I would like customize my node when the user create a new content type.

Click [HERE](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Cu1zuKaWF97J5LujfMv-lW7YOTENDtLALAPDQUO0tIA/edit) to know how my form works

But I don't know how to customize a node and apply a style. It should created a table with differents informations that the user has sent.

Are anyone of you has an idea of ​​how it works?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first image looks like everything is submitted as one field, is this correct?

If there were a way you could redo this as separate fields, it would be much easier to take your input and use it in many different ways, using Views.

Comment: Thank your for your help ! It's works for me. I'v used views, it's easier to do that !